# Closing of WCF service (ServiceHost) not as graceful as it seems

Tags: wcf, timeout, servicehost, netmsmqbinding

When I call `serviceHost.Close()`, even if I put a timeout value `serviceHost.Close(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))`, while it stops receiving messages, it seems one or two of my messages gets lost from time to time.

I want my service to stop in the middle of an operation, but process the rest of the messages already received. Is there a way to gracefully close the service while a message is still processing?

I already set the `closeTimeout` and `receiveTimeout` in the app.config to 10 minutes, also use `RequestAdditionalTime(600000)` but I still get this issue. It does not close in 10 minutes, rather 1 minute at max.

Binding I am using is **netMsmqBinding**.

**EDIT:**

I temporarily fixed the problem by adding a while statement in the `ServiceBase` method `OnStop` that if the process is not finish then it will keep looping. It seems like a dirty hack, but it works for now. Let me know if there's a cleaner way to end it gracefully.